# What is the difference between these cases? And how can I know what is a temporary object?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following error:

```
class B {
private:
    int n;
public:
    B(int x) :
            n(x) {
    }
    B operator+(B& b) {
        return B(n + b.n);
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const B& b) {
        out << "B: " << b.n;
        return out;
    }
    bool operator<(const B& rhs) const {
        return n < rhs.n;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b1(2);
    B b2(3);
    B res121 = b1 + (b2 + b1); // ----error
    B res21 = b2 + b1;
    B res1_21 = b1 + res21; // ---- No error
    cout << res1_21;
    return 0;
}
```

Why I get error while I try to define `res121` but don't get error while I try to define `res1_21` ?
After all, `b2+b1` is object in type of `B` , so what is the problem? What it's say that it's `a temporary object` , how can I know what is `temporary object` and what it's not.

Comment: the result of `b2+b1` is a temporary object. It is called temporary, as it ceases to exist at the `;`.

Comment: @Caleth So this is the only case of defining a temporary?

Comment: It's the only case of trying to call a function accepting lvalue reference on a temporary. The initialisation of `res121`, `res21` and `res1_21` theoretically involve copying temporaries, except the copy doesn't happen

Comment: @Caleth But I read in some sources that object that defined in scope is also a temporary object (so that if we will return it, if the function returns by-reference), so I don't understand it.

Comment: That's a different meaning of the word temporary

Comment: @Caleth So the intention in this context is an object that defined only in one line?

Comment: You cant do this "return B(n + b.n);" because it returns an object that is only in scope inside the operator+ definition.

Comment: @Katianie of course you can. You don't even need the `B(` ... `)`

Comment: The C++ standard only uses "temporary" in the "result of an expression" sense. It refers to local variables of a function as  "variables with automatic storage duration". Colloquially those are temporary because they cease to exist at the corresponding `}` of their definition

Comment: related/dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: @Caleth no you cant....its declared on the stack and gets deallocated once the function ends, also the answer mentions this.

Comment: @Katianie no, it's not *declared* at all. `B(n + b.n)` is an *expression* of type `B`, with the value-category pr-value. `return`ing it materialises it at the call site

Comment: @Katianie and if it were different, how could *any* values be returned by functions?

Comment: @Caleth You can return values for primitives but not for objects. It calls B(int) which is a constructor not an expression. The constructor then returns the memory location of the allocated memory and since it is not a pointer, that means the memory is allocated on the stack.

Comment: @Katianie go read [`[expr.post]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post) and [`[stmt.return]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return). You are looking at a *simple-type-specifier ( expression-list opt )* as the operand of `return`

Comment: @Caleth Intresting, but in [stmt.return] it says "Note: A return statement can involve an invocation of a constructor to perform a copy or move of the operand if it is not a prvalue or if its type differs from the return type of the function.
A copy operation associated with a return statement may be elided or converted to a move operation if an automatic storage duration variable is returned". Isen't B in this case an xvalue meaning it cannot be a prvalue?

Comment: no, it is a prvalue. xvalues have an identity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A temporary object in C++ terminology is an object with no name or identity that comes into existence, usually as the return value of a function.  How they work exactly changes between [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

Their existence ends at the end of the current full expression (usually a `;`), and they cannot bind to non-`const` lvalue references, so `B&` cannot bind to a temporary.

This:

```
B operator+(B& b) {
    return B(n + b.n);
}
```

is a poor `operator+`.  The best<sup>1</sup> way to write `operator+` is:

```
B& operator+=(B const& b)& {
  n += b.n;
  return *this;
}
friend B operator+(B lhs, B const& rhs) {
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

where you implement `+=` as a member function, then write a slightly asymmetric `friend` `operator+` that is implemented in terms of `+=`.

The assymetry in `+` makes long chains of `+` expressions slightly more efficient, especially if you implement cheap-to-move objects.

---

<sup>1</sup> Naturally there are situations where this isn't the best.  Like sometimes real expression templates.  But you should start with this and only get more complex if you prove you need it.

Comment: @storyteller it lets you create a short inline ADL forwarder that supports implicit typr conversions on both left and right.  You coukd put it outside thr class instrad, but given kts 2 line body...  plus, if thr class is a template, this pattern works better thsn mosg alternatives, as it generates a non trmplate operator + .for each template instance.